# Function calling in C++: Syntax help needed

Tags: c++, verilog

Have a look at the Verilog code below:

```
module first(input a, input b, output c)
assign c= a&b;
endmodule
```

And then we call this module into another module like as below

```
module second(input d, input e, output f)

first instance_name (.a(d), .b(e), .c(f));

endmodule
```

As we can clearly see that which port is connected with which port. While calling a function in C++, its always a danger that we will miss a port and place some unwanted variable there.

Is there any similar way of doing things in C++?

Comment: Please add the following information - a) A clearer description of what the verilog code does, and b) how you would write a function call in C++ and how that is insufficient to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: @cigien
 Its now clearly showing what it is doing.

Comment: You can't use named arguments in C++. But since the C++20 standard structure/class members can be named when initializing objects.

Comment: And if you don't provide all required arguments, or use the wrong type (and implicit conversion is not possible), the C++ compiler *will* complain.

Comment: See [here](https://pdimov.github.io/blog/2020/09/07/named-parameters-in-c20/) for what @Someprogrammerdude refers to – though to cover output parameters as well you'll have to include references in the struct – that has quite a smell if you don't provide a constructor for as well, but then again losing the possibility to use designated initialisers...

Comment: Actually for me, the bigger issue is to connect right variables with right ones. But thanks for tips by our respected posters.

Answer (score 3):

While C++ does not support named argument idiom out of box, it can be done with help of designated initializers:

```
struct t_Input
{
    t_Input(void) = delete;
    t_Input(int) {}
};

struct t_Args
{
    t_Input a;
    t_Input b;
    t_Input c;
};

void First(t_Args args);

void Second()
{
    //First({.a{1}, .c{3}}); // error
    First({.a{1}, .b{2}, .c{3}});
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:15,endLineNumber:10,positionColumn:15,positionLineNumber:10,selectionStartColumn:15,selectionStartLineNumber:10,startColumn:15,startLineNumber:10),source:%27struct+t_Input%0A%7B%0A++++t_Input(void)+%3D+delete%3B%0A++++t_Input(int)+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+t_Args%0A%7B%0A++++t_Input+a%3B%0A++++t_Input+b%3B%0A++++t_Input+c%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+First(t_Args+args)%3B%0A%0Avoid+Second()%0A%7B%0A++++First(%7B.a%7B1%7D,+.b%7B2%7D,+.c%7B3%7D%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g131,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-Wconversion+-Wpedantic%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+13.1%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+13.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Also modern IDEs, such as Visual Studio, offer handy inline hints feature:
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't rename the functions, though ;)

Comment: I am using the VS, and there is no such thing is shown. Do I have to enable it in the IDE?

Comment: This answer doesn't cover the fact that `c` and `f` (which got lost here entirely) apparently are *output* parameters.

Comment: @JohnMcnZ I think they were added in VS2022 https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aDrJ.png

Comment: @Aconcagua It's not a big deal. *output* parameters can be returned from function, or a pass by reference used instead of pass by value.

Comment: Indeed, but still it's lacking. Question author appears rather inexperienced and might need such information, big deal or not...

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to naming the arguments in a C++ function when calling it. No, this is not possible.

A good IDE will nevertheless label your arguments for you.

Comment: any good ide suggestion?

Comment: @JohnMcnZ Just Clion for C++.. (a highly configured emacs is even better in my opinion. You then have to install a proper LSP-Server)

Comment: @JohnMcnZ I personally have been running with [eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2023-03/r/eclipse-ide-cc-developers) for years now. Some might argue about the choice, but there's simply nothing else that fits my personal needs better... And in contrast to Clion its open-source, thus free. About function arguments: Eclipse shows the complete signature on hovering the mouse over the function name.